# How can a Jewish convict repair public Chillul Hashem?

Tags: chilul-kidush-hashem, kaparah-atonement

I'm going to use the recent [conviction of Sheldon Silver](http://nypost.com/2015/11/30/sheldon-silver-found-guilty-on-all-counts-in-corruption-trial/) as an example.

Synopsis / Context (esp. since the above link may become a "cobweb" link:

> Silver, a 71-year-old veteran lawmaker who was once one of the most
>   powerful politicians in the state, was found guilty of honest-services
>   fraud, extortion and money-laundering for trading political favors to
>   enrich himself and then lying about it.
>
> He now faces a maximum of 130 years behind bars, although under
>   federal sentencing guidelines, he will likely get no more than 20
>   years.

Since Sheldon Silver is Jewish, he probably caused a public *Chilul Hashem*. Many people will likely point to the fact that he is a corrupt Jew and will state that this is common Jewish behavior.

Lets say Mr. Silver gets a long jail sentence. Few will know what he is doing while he is in jail. How could he attempt to repair his reputation to the public so that they can see that he is trying to correct his sin?

Comment: I would expect the correct course of action in each case to be entirely dependent on the individual, the crime, the communal context, etc.

Comment: @IsaacMoses OK. I think one example may do as an answer.

Comment: but what may be a good idea in one set of circumstances may be a bad idea in another.

Comment: Isn't going to jail the tikun?

Comment: @CraigFeinstein it may be the *tikun*. But, my question's focus is regardng repairing the **public** viewpoint. I.e. - if he's in jail and doing repeartion, who knows about it?

Comment: @DanF It is public record that he is in jail. Jail is "paying one's debt to society". He has been humiliated greatly from this; I would think it also pays for the chillul Hashem. People know that Jews aren't perfect and don't expect them to be perfect. A chillul Hashem is created when people get the impression that it is the Torah or Hashem that is at fault. It is Jews who do the right thing who atone for this. That's just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Orchot Tzadikim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orchot_Tzaddikim) ([Shaar HaTeshuva](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38360&st=&pgnum=152)), the problem with Chillul Hashem is that people see the practice and learn from it. Therefore the way to repair Chillul Hashem is to publicly exhort people not to learn from his ways and to publicly admit his guilt and explain what he is doing to atone.